# Understanding syntax of function parameter: vector<vector<int>> A[]

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, c++14, stdvector

I'm solving a question where a function is defined as following:

```
vector <int> func(int a, vector<vector<int>> B[]){
    // Some stuff
}
```

I'm confused about why the second parameter is not simply `vector<vector<int>> B`. Why the extra `[]` part in the parameter? Can someone clarify the meaning of this?

The vector, `B`, is populated by a similar code snippet:

```
vector<vector<int>> B[10]; 
while(num--){
    cin>>u>>v>>w;
    vector<int> t1,t2;
    t1.push_back(v);
    t1.push_back(w);
    B[u].push_back(t1);
    t2.push_back(u);
    t2.push_back(w);
    B[v].push_back(t2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as `int foo(char str[])` is a function that takes a (c-style) array of characters, so `int foo(vector<vector<int>> B[])` takes an array of vectors of vectors ... of integers. This means that it's three-dimensional data, requiring 3 indices to access the elements (fundamental data type; in this case, `int`), like `B[i][j][k] = 5`. Without the extra `[]` in the API it'd be two-dimensional data: a vector of vectors.

Note that `int foo(char str[])` is equivalent to `int foo(char str[5])` which is equivalent to `int foo(char * str)`.
In `C` we usually add the `[]` to a function declaration to imply that we expect to receive an array of those elements; while `*` is often used when we expect at most one element. Likewise, adding the number `[5]` is basically just a comment to the user of the code that they expect `5` elements, but the compiler won't enforce this. These conventions carry over to `C++` when we use these c-style arrays ... which is rare.

With c-style arrays there's either going to be a maximum array size in the comments somewhere; or, more commonly, it's provided as an input. That may be what the first argument of the function is supposed to represent.

I agree with `KungPhoo` here that this API looks suspiciously bad. I'd expect bugs/bad performance just because the choices seem very amateurish. The c-style array means the function can't know where the end of the c-style array is - but the vectors mean that we give up some of the (niche) benefits of c-style simplicity (especially because they're nested!). It seems to be getting the worst of both worlds. But, perhaps, there may be a ***very*** niche justification for the API.

Answer (score 0):

B ist a static array (C-style) of 10 elements [0 .. 9]. It's not safe and this code is a terrible mess.
Better use std::array<std::vector<str::vector<int>>, 10> B; instead to have index checking.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. But can you explain why the parameter is vector<vector<int>> B[] instead of just vector<vector<int>> B ?

Comment: @Elliott Thanks. Can you post it as answer. So I can accept it as solved.